# Can't access model from another django app duration migration

Tags: python, django, migration

My migration with custom logic attempts to use`Model3` from `otherapp` but it fails with `LookupError: App 'otherapp' doesn't have a 'model3' model.`

Model3 is not a new model, it's been in use for a while and I can access other models in `otherapp` during my migration.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def update_items(apps, schema_editor):

    # apps shows references to models in 'otherapp'
    # This prints Model1, Model2 but is missing Model3
    print apps.all_models['otherapp'].keys()

    # This works
    OtherAppModel1 = apps.get_model('otherapp', 'Model1')

    # This fails: LookupError: App 'otherapp' doesn't have a 'model3' model.
    OtherAppModel3 = apps.get_model('otherapp', 'Model3')

    # This works but should not be done in a migration
    from otherapp.models import Model3

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('thisapp', '0102_foo'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_items)
    ]
```

Comment: Try adding the other app's latest migration as a dependency, [as the docs suggest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#accessing-models-from-other-apps).

Comment: Do you import one model from another app and another model in the first app?